# How to display tool tip over a transparent image placed on a Winform button

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I am displaying a transparent icon (32x32) of a red triangle in the upper right of a button control that signifies an error exists.  Additionally, when the user hovers over the icon, a tool tip is displayed.

I have been able to display the icon and the associated tool tip.  The problem is a transparent 32x32 icon with the red triangle being only 12x12.  The tool tip should only trigger when hovering over the red triangle and not the transparent space.

Attempts have been made to display the triangle as a button as well as a picture box, however the tool tip still triggers in the transparent space.  Additionally, the error provider was first used as a goal of what I am trying to accomplish.

UI items:

- Button control: "btnAttachments"
- Error Provider control: "errManager"

  ```
  public class StackTest
  {
      private static Dictionary<string, Control> _errorMessages = new Dictionary<string, Control>();

      public StackTest()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          InitErrors();
      }
      private void InitErrors()
      {
          _errorMessages.Clear();
          AddErrorControl(btnAttachments, "Missing file attachment(s).");
          //errManager.SetError(btnAttachments, "Missing file attachment(s)."); errManager.SetIconPadding(btnAttachments, -32);
      }

      private void AddErrorControl(Control control, string message = null, Enum selectedImage = null, EventHandler handler = null)
      {
          string name = "errFor" + control.Name;
          if (_errorMessages.ContainsKey(name)) { return; }

          Button errorIcon = CreateErrorControl(name, control);
          errorIcon.BackgroundImage = Theme.GetImage(selectedImage ?? eImages_OtherIcons.Error_TopRight_Small);

          //PictureBox errorIcon = CreateErrorControl2(name);
          //errorIcon.Image = Theme.GetImage(selectedImage ?? eImages_OtherIcons.Error_TopRight_Small);
          //errorIcon.Image = Bitmap.FromHicon((Theme.GetIcon(selectedImage ?? eImages_OtherIcons.Error_TopRight_Small)).Handle);

          if (null != handler) { errorIcon.Click += handler; }
          new ToolTip().SetToolTip(errorIcon, message);
          errorIcon.Tag = message;

          control.Controls.Add(errorIcon);
          control.Controls[name].Location = new Point(control.Width - errorIcon.Width +20 , 0 );
          _errorMessages.Add(name, errorIcon);
      }

      private Button CreateErrorControl(string name, Control control)
      {
          var errorIcon = new Button();
          errorIcon.Name = name;
          errorIcon.Size = new Size(32, 32);
          //errorIcon.Location = new Point(control.Width - errorIcon.Width, 0);
          errorIcon.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
          errorIcon.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
          errorIcon.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
          errorIcon.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
          errorIcon.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
          errorIcon.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
          errorIcon.Visible = false;

          return errorIcon;
      }

      private PictureBox CreateErrorControl2(string name) 
      {
          var errorIcon = new PictureBox();
          errorIcon.Name = name;
          errorIcon.Size = new Size(32, 32);
          errorIcon.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
          errorIcon.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
          errorIcon.Visible = false;

          return errorIcon;
      }
  }
  ```

The built in Error Provider control achieves the desire results that I would like to replicate.  Doing so will allow for a more robust application with  more custom functionality then what the error provider offers.

Comment: try to Place 12x12 transparent image over the triangle and wire the logic to the image.

Comment: Why not just inherit the button in a new class and do anything you need with it?

Comment: You could create a bitmap of the button (drawtobitmap and store in Tag, maybe) and use getpixel to decide if you want to show the tooltip.

Comment: @TaW Using GraphicsPath to draw the shape on the control and, on MouseMove, `GraphicsPath.IsVisible(e.Location)`

Comment: Yup, another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the GetPixel suggestion from @TaW, I did further R&D and now have something functional.  The Tag of the picture box contains the tool tip message to be displayed.  With the picture box being the "sender" of the mouse move, it was easy to extract the image back to a bitmap.

Thanks to all for the feedback.

First, I switched the testing to use CreateErrorControl2 with the PictureBox and added in a MouseMove.

```
    private PictureBox CreateErrorControl2(string name) //, Control control)
    {
        var errorIcon = new PictureBox();
        errorIcon.Name = name;
        errorIcon.Size = new Size(32, 32);
        errorIcon.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        errorIcon.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        errorIcon.Visible = false;
        errorIcon.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(DisplayToolTip);

        return errorIcon;
    }
```

The following code was also added in support of the DisplayToolTip method.

```
    private bool _toolTipShown = false;

    private bool IsTransparent(PictureBox pb, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Color pixel = ((Bitmap)pb.Image).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
        return (0 == pixel.A && 0 == pixel.R && 0 == pixel.G && 0 == pixel.B);
    }

    private void DisplayToolTip(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        IsTransparent((PictureBox)control, e);
        if (IsTransparent((PictureBox)control, e))
        {
            _toolTip.Hide(control);
            _toolTipShown = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!_toolTipShown)
            {
                _toolTip.Show(control.Tag.ToString(), control);
                _toolTipShown = true;
            }
        }
    }
```